# How to solve the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE error?

Tags: django

i installed wsgi, python, apache and django on my Ubuntu 10.04 but when i

```
django-admin.py runserver
```

i get this error

```
Error: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

how to solve this?any replies will be much appreciated.... and a step by step answers will be great,,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.

```
function setdsm() {
    # add the current directory and the parent directory to PYTHONPATH
    # sets DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD/..
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$PWD
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then 
        x=${PWD/\/[^\/]*\/}
        export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$x.settings
    else    
        export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$1
    fi

    echo "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set to $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"
}
```

put this in  .bash_profile, then a quick setdsm sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to the settings.py in the current directory and add the current directory and it’s parent to PYTHONPATH.

Taken from: http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/django_settings_module/ 
Check this also: http://martinjansen.com/2008/10/20/django-settings-files-for-development-and-production/

Hope this helps.

Comment: export PYTHONPATH=$/home/idarine/neophyte/:$PWD/..
export PYTHONPATH=$/home/idarine/:$PWD -----------is this right?i substituted my current django directory and my parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are trying to run django server using `djang-admin.py runserver`  script instead of `./manage.py runserver`. In a nutshell, you should use `django-admin.py` to create your application, and manage.py to run development server, commands etc for current django application, for example:

```
django-admin.py startproject test
cd test
./manage.py runserver
```

Hope this helps.