# Django environment variable undefined

Tags: 11.10, django

On running Django, I frequently get the following error:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

How do I set the environment variables correctly? I tried the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26766/how-to-solve-the-django-settings-module-error) here but did not have any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an environment variable with a command like:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=application.settings
```

Assuming that `application.settings` is in Python's path, you should then be able to run `django-admin` using those settings.  Alternatively, you can pass a settings module to `django-admin` on the command line:

```
django-admin --settings=application.settings ...
```

Comment: I get the error `ImportError: Could not import settings 'application.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named application.settings` how can i set this to the python path?

Comment: No worries. I figured it out.